# Docker Compose profiles feature: deprecated?

Tags: docker-compose

Docker Compose online guides describe the **profiles** feature that allows to run different containers described in the same configuration file just using different profiles with option `--profile` : [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/) (in short) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) (in details).

The `profiles` compose file option (describing for which profiles a service should run) is mentioned in [compose file 3.0 format specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#profiles) without any other version restrictions, so it looks like it should work for all 3.* versions.

But the instances of Docker Compose that I have installed on my Windows workstation and on my dev server under CentOS 7 (both has version **1.27.4**, build **40524192**) just doesn't have this option in their CLI. The `docker-compose --help` command shows no `--profile` option in its output, and it really doesn't work when I try it. Instead, there are `--context` and `--env-file` options (that are absent in the online guide), but it looks like both are something different.

Does anyone know what's happened with Docker Compose profiles? Are this feature removed (I was unable to find anything about it)? Or are they available in different mode or something (I know that some options work only for `docker stack`, not for `docker-compose`, but the former one doesn't have it too neighter in online descrition nor in `--help` output)? Or do I do something wrong?

Comment: See the release notes, it was added in [1.28.0](https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/#1280): *"- Added support for service profiles."*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [clcto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2721883/clcto) answered, the version of Docker Compose that I used is just too old: to use **profiles**, version **1.28.0** or later is required.

For Windows, the usual way to receive Docker Compose is to install Docker Desktop that contains Docker, Docker Compose and more, and the actual version of Docker Desktop still contains Docker Compose 1.27.4. As a workaround, I downloaded corresponding Docker Compose exe file from [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) and replaced the existing `c:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-compose.exe` file with it — it was enough.